# Rewrite URL with RewriteRule using url Variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Ok, I have a link http://www.cuadmemo.com/posts.php?id=2861 and want it to show like this
http://www.cuadmemo.com/2861
I have in the .htaccess file this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  posts.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$  posts.php?id=$1
```

Have tried a number of different solutions that I read on this site but none seem to work this far. Any suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Make sure we don't rewrite directories and existing files        
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ posts.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: few seconds faster than me, I deleted my answer :)

Comment: I added this to the .htaccess file but it still gives me the same result :(. I am pulling the data for the links in if statements to only post stories from the current day or previous day and ect. Does that have something to do with it? I am using hostgator as the web server provider under a reseller account if that helps.

Comment: Please try the updated answer with the *RewriteBase* directive

Comment: .htaccess can be used with Apache only, make sure your vhost config has the `AllowOverride All` directive, put the .htaccess file into your document root. Simple test to make sure the .htaccess is read at all is to add invalid markup - your browser will show an `internal server error`